# How to check for data from 3 different thread in android

Tags: android

I am launching 3 async thread in on create function and once data is available for all 3 threads launching a new activity.

This is my current code.

```
Class MainActivity{
    private ArrayList<A> alist = new  ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<B> blist = new  ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<C> clist = new  ArrayList<>();


    onCreate(){
        call loadDataA() in async thread
        call loadDataB() in async thread
        call loadDataC() in async thread
    }

    loadDataA(){
        if(dataLoadSuccess){
            alist = data from server;
            if(alist.size() > 0 && blist.size() > 0 && alist.size() > 0){
                launch B activity
            }
        }
    }

    loadDataB(){

        if(dataLoadSuccess){
            blist = data from server;
            if(alist.size() > 0 && blist.size() > 0 && alist.size() > 0){
                launch B activity
            }
        }
    }

    loadDatac(){
        if(dataLoadSuccess){
            clist = data from server;
            if(alist.size() > 0 && blist.size() > 0 && alist.size() > 0){
                launch B activity
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Here this code

```
if(alist.size() > 0 && blist.size() > 0 && alist.size() > 0){
    launch new activity here
}
```

is duplicate for all 3 functions. and i feel this is not proper way to check for data availability.

Can someone help me what is proper android way to check for data availability in above case.

Comment: why do you need launching 3 activities?

Comment: Why you store data in Three different ArrayList  ?

Comment: It is not 3 activities, just a single activity if data available from all 3 async call

Comment: @MD, Because data is of different type.

Comment: That means you request Three AsyncTask at the same time. Am i right? Better to make AsyncTask call one by one. If first response found then go to 2nd one and if 2nd response found then go to 3rd.

Comment: what you can do is instead of putting the same code at 3 places, create a single method which does all these checks. and call that method on completion of all the three threads. Also instead of checking the size of the list, you can use getStatus() method which tells you whether the thread is still running or finished execution

Comment: @MD i can do that to. But i feel let not put any code for checking variables in async task. Async task just get data and set it to respective variable. I am looking for some other kind of android way (like observer pattern) to check for data and launch new activity once all 3 data is available.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal still we will checking the data variables 3 times right?? I just want to avoid that.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Go with the `RxJava` then may be helps you.

Comment: Go with @MD Suggestion . Call AsyncTask one by one. First call one AsyncTask. In postExecute of first asynctask call second asynctask and in postexecute of second asynctask call third asynctask.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani If i am calling AsyncTask one by one, i will be making network call sequential. But i feel as they are  independent we should call them the same way they are currently..

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [CountDownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). From the documentation:

> A CountDownLatch initialized to N can be used to make one thread wait until N threads have completed some action, or some action has been completed N times.
>
> A useful property of a CountDownLatch is that it doesn't require that threads calling countDown wait for the count to reach zero before proceeding, it simply prevents any thread from proceeding past an await until all threads could pass.

Therefore you can do something like:

1. Initialize a `CountDownLatch` in your `Activity`

   ```
   CountDownLatch mLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);
   ```
2. Find a way to access `mLatch` in your `AsyncTask`. If your `AsyncTask` is a nested class in your `Activity` then you can just access `mLatch` directly.
3. Call `mLatch.countDown()` in each `AsyncTask` after data is loaded.
4. Create and run a `AsyncTask` (or a background `Thread`) that wait for the three data to be loaded. The reason is that `await()` is a blocking method and we do not want to call it on the UI Thread.

   ```
   mLatch.await();
   // Launch new activity here
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used the AtomicInteger class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Its allow you to create async counter where would check if all of your tasks ended than do what you want.